# Can't move cursor to empty p tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Ok this problem is driving me crazy.

I am implementing the functionality for an enter key in a content editable div. When the user presses enter, I create a new p tag and append it to the document in its place or split the nodes if the user presses enter in the middle of a paragraph. All is working properly however I found this problem.

If I append an empty p tag without adding contents in it `<p></p>` when the user types his first letter after enter, the cursor does not move to this p tag. If however I add a space `<p>&nbsp;</p>` it's ok. Obviously I don't want to add a space each time I add a new paragraph.

I tried to solve this problem by adding a character, say 'A', moving the cursor there and removing the 'A' afterwards. However it's still the same problem.

Any ideas why is this happening and what can I do for a workaround?

**EDIT:** I tried to hide the first letter by css `visibility:hidden` but then the p tag is ignored completely!

Comment: Add an empty `<p class="new">&nbsp;</p>` with a distinctive class. When the user types their own character, remove the class and the `&nbsp;`

Comment: huh I guess it could work! needed a new perspective I guess! Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Add width and height to your `<p />` element and change the display property to block or inline-block

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;  
    height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: nope didn't work either :( still the cursor doesnt recognize the empty tag

Comment: the problem is not that the paragraph is not showing, it's that the cursor cant move to it and write in it